# How does a servlets filter identify next destination is another filter or a servlet/jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

We usually end up with writing `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in web.xml for any Filter in servlets.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestRedirectorFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`.
```

Now my doubt is how java identifies which is next servlet/jsp is? Because any request we make through

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/ABCXYZ").forward(request, (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse);
```

to navigate on next servlet/jsp, container by  default is going to search in web.xml. And in web.xml `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`  is already there for the filter we use. Exactly here actual problem begins.

If `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` [which is acting like a universal receiver for any request] is already there in web.xml then How the heck container knows to follow `<url-pattern>/ABCXYZ</url-pattern>` instead `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` ?  Please share your views and knowledge on this front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Servlet Matching Procedure**

A request may match more than one servlet-mapping in a given context. The servlet container uses a straightforward matching procedure to determine the best match.

**The matching procedure has four simple rules.**

- First, the container prefers an **exact path match** over a wildcard path match.
- Second, the container prefers to match the **longest pattern**.
- Third, the container prefers **path matches over filetype** matches.
- Finally, the pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` always matches any request that no other pattern matches.

---

For example, a context web.xml file can map the home page for an online catalog to one pattern and the search page for the catalog to a different pattern, as shown below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>catalogBrowse</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Catalog/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>catalogSearch</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Catalog/search/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below figure illustrates the matching process for a context. Since the container prefers to match the **longest pattern**, a URL that includes `/Catalog/search/` always matches the mapping for catalogSearch rather than the mapping for catalogBrowse.

**URL pattern matching**

[image]

---

*It is copied form the below link if your are not interested to go to the link.*

Please have a look at [URL Patterns](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html) where it is described in detail with examples.

Comment: Your explanation and given link helped me.