# HTTP 404 error on existing page nohandlerfound - no mapping found

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

**Error:**

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/summary/homePage.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My page exists in that directory and if the url pattern is setup like `<url-pattern>/ANYSTRING/*</url-pattern>` my pages work just fine. To elaborate: My controller uses `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")`. When the url pattern is `/potato/*` and I navigate to `localhost:8080/potato/home` my page works perfectly. But if I keep the same settings with the url pattern being `/*` it gives me the 404.

**Tried:**

1. Using a jsp servlet mapping to my pages directory, but it causes other mapping problems.
2. adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to spring-servlet, but this displays the source of my page.
3. Change url pattern to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` but it causes other mapping problems.

Could anyone shed some light on my problem? I am editing as I try different possible solutions.

Comment: why can't you use `<url-pattern>/ANYSTRING/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: @Braj it became a redundant string so I simply want it gone, it is just more to type now.

Comment: Then make it in this way `<url-pattern>/CosntactString/ANYSTRING/*</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with  `<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>` pattern.

You can define multiple url-pattern for the same servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/abc/xyz/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

It might help you to understand the `url-pattern`

### Servlet Matching Procedure

A request may match more than one servlet-mapping in a given context. The servlet container uses a straightforward matching procedure to determine the best match.

#### The matching procedure has four simple rules.

- First, the container prefers an **exact path match** over a wildcard path match.
- Second, the container prefers to match the **longest pattern**.
- Third, the container prefers **path matches over filetype** matches.
- Finally, the pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` always matches any request that no other pattern matches.

---

Have a look at my post [How does a servlets filter identify next destination is another filter or a servlet/jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698639/how-does-a-servlets-filter-identify-next-destination-is-another-filter-or-a-serv/23699625#23699625) for detailed description.

#### Problem Solved:

Add this mapping to handle the jsp pages directly (web.xml):

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Add this to make the rest of the resources in the project accessible  (spring-servlet.xml):

`<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>`

Comment: I get the 404 on the page without the console giving me a mapping problem with `*.jsp` - i am looking into the rest of your answer now.

Comment: What is the URL formed?

Comment: Please read [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Comment: I add `<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>` and the page shows but I get problems with other mappings like bootstrap? - I am still trying to read through everything you gave me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I added the above to handle the pages then I added `<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"/>` to handle the rest of the resources. If you find a way to include this in an edit I will accept your answer.

Comment: Finally you got the solution. I just give you an idea. You are genius. :) My master says :- A hint is enough for an intelligent guy.

Comment: accept my edit and i will accept your answer since that is how i solved it

Answer (score 0):

And your controller RequestMapping?

"/*" makes your servlet intercept all kinds of requestmapping, so if there's not a correspondent methode it won't find the right methode and gives "no mapping".

This is because your files in WEB-INF are not publicly accessible.

I suggest you to use some suffix in the url-pattern , something like ".do" .

Comment: My mappings and controllers work fine if the url pattern is `/potato/*`, why would `/*` give me a problem?

Comment: can you post your controller? do you have this in the controller? >@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "potato")

Comment: No, that is not what I was referring to. The url pattern is in `web.xml` and my controller uses `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")`. When the url pattern is `/potato/*` and I navigate to `localhost:8080/potato/home` my page works perfectly. - added this to my question for others in case it is confusing.

Comment: well, weird, what I've understood is. by setting url-pattern     "/" or     "/*", the servlet will capture all of the request. In this case, if you try     localhost:8080/potato/whatever, it won't find the right mapping, but if you use a correct mapping which exists in your controller, it will somehow redirect the page according to your  viewResolver setting. better don't use "/" or "/*" I think.

Comment: well. if you are using .jsp suffix as url pattern, don't forget to modify the mapping. home  ->   home.jsp