# sending data from java servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send a string from a Java servlet to JSP but I always get a null in the string

### `Test.java` servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String s = "HelloWolrd";
    System.out.println(s);
    response.setContentType("text/jsp");
    request.setAttribute("s", s);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

### `test.jsp`

```
<body><%= request.getAttribute("s")%> </body>
```

`web.xml` has servlet class mapped to apis. Test and url-pattern as `/test`.

[image: My Directory structure]

Answer (score 0):

The `test.jsp` file is placed outside the `WEB-INF` as per your project structure. Validate it again.

Servlet:

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String s = "HelloWolrd";
        System.out.println(s);
        response.setContentType("text/jsp");
        request.setAttribute("s", s);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");       // CHANGE IT HERE
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>XYZ/servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>apis.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XYZ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

Have a look at my another post [How does a servlets filter identify next destination is another filter or a servlet/jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698639/how-does-a-servlets-filter-identify-next-destination-is-another-filter-or-a-serv/23699625#23699625) for detailed description on **Servlet Matching Procedure** used for `url-pattern`.

**Note:** Always try to avoid *Scriplet* instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Comment: nope that dint make any difference and the previous values <% = request.getAttribute("s") are also null. :(

Comment: can you explain the flow of the application and share the `web.xml` as well for quicker solution.

Comment: I am a newbie and I am just trying to send a string value from servlet to jsp page once the page is requested .  User requests the page localhost:8080/Traders/test.jsp and the string value s needs to be displayed thats yet

Comment: Is jsp calling properly from Servlet? Try with dummy data first in jsp.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but I think it has nothing to do with form. Though it may be an issue I dont see form being submitted anywhere. OP is trying to access an attribute in JSP set in the servlet.

Comment: Yes I have edited my post but that is the another issue that will be encountered once this issue is resolved. In JPS `apis/Test` is used in form as `action` and url-pattern `/test` is defiend in `web.xml`.

Comment: The `test.jsp` file is placed outside the `WEB-INF` as per your project structure. Look at the my edited post again.

Comment: i edited my code as per ur suggestion by changing /WEB-INF/test.jsp to /test.jsp but dint work . I have tried all the suggestions I still get a null value :( please help me out with this . Thankx

Comment: Simply share the files and step to execute the flow. I have already asked you how the flow is designed. What URL is passed in the browser.

Comment: my web.xml http://pastebin.com/JQ8gZB1K   , Test.java http://pastebin.com/rgRLb3VB ,  http://pastebin.com/nm6LDedq test.jsp

Comment: `web.xml` looks fine. Have you tried with just hello message in the jsp file.

Comment: By hello world u mean just to echo hello world on screen ? Yes i did and it works:(

Answer (score -1):

Also as per your eclipse directory structure you have your JSP under WebContent folder. So you need to do

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/traders/test.jsp");
```

Few other thing you can try

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/traders/test.jsp?s=s");
```

and then in your JSP you can do

```
<%= request.getAttribute("s")%>
```

OR

you can use Session

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("s", "s");
```

and do

```
<%= session.getAttribute( "s" ) %>
```

Comment: It dint work can you please see if my web.xml mappings are correct . Thankx.

Comment: You have not provided web.xml contents. If your page is indeed getting forwarded and you are getting null for the attribute there is no issue with mappings.

Comment: servlet class mapping <servlet-class>apis.Test</servlet-class>    and      url-mapping <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>

Comment: Make the url `<url-pattern>/test*</url-pattern>`.In this case if your URL is `http://localhost:8080/Traders/test.jsp` you will hit your apis.Test servlet.