# Can I do this complex url mapping in web container using servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

There are two servlets: A,B

A mapping to: `/*`

B mapping to: `/sub_dir/*`

if the url is in `/sub_dir/*` then it processed by B, else by A.

Comment: What do you mean _if the url is in `/sub_dir/*`_?

Comment: To do this you would want to bypass the container url mapping. So, you would setup a servlet to handle /* and then parse the url string yourself and direct traffic as you see fit using the RequestDispatcher.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes! maybe I should say " if the url of the request matched by the /sub_dir/*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to understand the `url-pattern`

### Servlet Matching Procedure

A request may match more than one servlet-mapping in a given context. The servlet container uses a straightforward matching procedure to determine the best match.

#### The matching procedure has four simple rules.

- First, the container prefers an **exact path match** over a wildcard path match.
- Second, the container prefers to match the **longest pattern**.
- Third, the container prefers **path matches over filetype** matches.
- Finally, the pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` always matches any request that no other pattern matches.

---

Have a look at my another post [How does a servlets filter identify next destination is another filter or a servlet/jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698639/how-does-a-servlets-filter-identify-next-destination-is-another-filter-or-a-serv/23699625#23699625) for detailed description.

> Can I do this complex url mapping in web container using servlet?

Yes, you can create a complex url mapping by just keeping the rules in the mind.

In your case most specific or longest url-pattern `/sub_dir/*` takes higher precedence over `/*` as per rule.